# What kind of control is this?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I've noticed many apps have settings pages which have controls which behave like buttons, but don't look like buttons.

Anyone know what type of controls these are?

Specifically the one I am tapping on in the linked video file below:

[Video example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leWuXqCirSRnsLFaRFyQmLQRvBLFAXu4/view?usp=drivesdk).

Comment: I don't know if there is a specific name for it, but if it is a `<TableView>`, then it might be possible to attach a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `ViewCell`s.

Comment: it looks like a TapGestureRecognizer attached to any view

Comment: I think he is looking for the TouchEffect library but its not ported to Maui yet, May be I should pick that up.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a regular control but to do this in Maui you can use the Popup control  to replicate a behaviour which is similar to what you just showed

Create a popup [as shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup):

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       

    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
               x:Class="MyProject.SimplePopup">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is a very important message!" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</toolkit:Popup>
```

Its cs file :

```
public partial class SimplePopup : Popup
{
    public SimplePopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And then use [Radiobuttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/radiobutton) from Maui to achieve the UI you need.

And for that effect use [touch effects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QKFsI7zcts&ab_channel=XamarinDevelopers) Its being ported to Maui at the moment though As far as I know (not sure if works as a compatibility package).

Answer (score 1):

It's a picker control, you can get more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker

```
<StackLayout>
<Label Text="Theme"
        Margin="0,25,0,5"
        FontAttributes="Bold"/>
<Picker x:Name="picker"
        Title="Select theme">
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Light</x:String>
            <x:String>Dark</x:String>
            <x:String>Black</x:String>
            <x:String>Automatic (device theme)</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

Android:
[Android picker example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdjrh.jpg)

Windows: [Windows picker example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfd2n.png)